# Get access to AppDomain in another app?

Tags: .net, appdomain, code-injection

I'm trying to extend a freeware, proprietary piece of .Net 2.0 software, and it's been giving me grief. I successfully managed to inject a Win32 dll and get it to successfully load in the .Net dll into the primary app domain, but doing so caused their custom GUI system to lock up completely.

Is it possible to get a reference to a remote AppDomain (running in another app) and perform operations on it (e.g. load an assembly, create a class)?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm sure I saw something when I was poking around with the Win32 hosting API, but I can't find it again...

Comment: You were given a strong hint when the GUI locked up. If their code wasn't written to be successfully extended, then chances are that any extension will likely fail to be successful.

Comment: @John-Saunders The GUI locked up when an assembly was injected, regardless of whether it even contained code. I would have debugged it, but the program in question is also x64, which caused remote debugging issues.

Comment: yeah, like I said. The freeware code is clearly not made to be extended in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they say about security is totally true, however, there are some tools that can let you do what you want to (modify the app on runtime?)

Have a look at:

**Cecil**  http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil

In simple English, with Cecil, you can load existing managed assemblies, browse all the contained types, modify them on the fly and save back to the disk the modified assembly.

**Crack.NET**   http://cracknetproject.codeplex.com/

Once you find an object or type that you're interested in, you can manipulate it, and others, by writing and executing an IronPython script.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't get a reference to another AppDomain. AppDomains are isolated. Otherwise all the .NET code would be completely unsecured.